# Animation of dynamically generated menu not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have one left side menu, which has multiple parent menus and under them certain child menus. I want to provide these menus a functionality similar to accordion. Like if I select one menu item, then its child menus will get visible (`slideDown` animation) and the child menu of the active parent menu will hide (`slideUp` animation). In addition to this functionality, the selected menu will always be on top and other menus will come under it.

Below is the code snippet for the same:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.dropdown').find('li:eq(0)').addClass('active');
    $('.dropdown').find('[data-id="parentmenu"]').each(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('active') == false) {
            $(this).find('ul').slideUp(10);
        }
    });
    $('ul.dropdown').on('click', '[data-id="parentmenu"]', function () {
        $(this).siblings('[data-id="parentmenu"]').removeClass('active');
        $(this).siblings('[data-id="parentmenu"]').each(function () {
            $(this).find('ul').slideUp(500);
        });
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).find('ul').show().slideDown(500);
        $markupHTML = "<li data-id='parentmenu'>" + $(this).html() + "</li>";
        $($markupHTML).insertBefore($('.dropdown').find('li:eq(0)'));
        $(this).remove();
    });

});
```

```css
ul.dropdown {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.dropdown {
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 203px;
}
ul.dropdown li a {
    color: #7f7f7f;
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul.dropdown li {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #91a6ca;
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
}
#left_panel {
    background-color: #fff;
    float: left;
    min-height: 700px;
    min-width: 230px;
    padding: 15px 3px;
    width: 12%;
}
.ui-resizable {
    position: relative;
}
.vdr-left-nav {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vdr-left-nav ui-resizable" id="left_panel">
<ul class="dropdown">
    <li data-id="parentmenu" class="active">
        <a title="" href="#" class="snacks"> Menu 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li data-id="childmenu"> <a href="#">Child Menu 1</a></li>
            <li data-id="childmenu"> <a href="#">Child Menu 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li data-id="parentmenu">
        <a title="" href="#" class="snacks"> Menu 2</a>
        <ul >
            <li data-id="childmenu"><a href="#">Child Menu 3</a></li>
            <li data-id="childmenu"><a href="#">Child Menu 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li data-id="parentmenu">
        <a title="" href="#" class="snacks"> Menu 3</a>
        <ul >
            <li data-id="childmenu"><a href="#">Child Menu 5</a></li>
            <li data-id="childmenu"><a href="#">Child Menu 6</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The code is almost working properly, except that I could not get the `slideDown` animation to work for the top most selected menu item. The selected menu is just shown and the animation just does not work at all.

Also tried with `$(this).find('ul').slideDown(500).show();` but this is also not working. What am I doing wrong?

Any help will be appreciated.

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w0d8sdvo/1/) for the same as well.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/w0d8sdvo/2/

Comment: @user5200704: The animation works as expected, but the selected menu item will be the topmost menu item, like in my fiddle

Comment: but your code is working fine as you want topmost menu item displaying selected.

Comment: @user5200704: Yes but the `slideDown` animation is not working. I want the `slideDown` animation to work for the top most selected element.

Comment: I am not sure but try this https://jsfiddle.net/w0d8sdvo/3/

Comment: @user5200704 Yes this is what I needed. Put this as answer so that I can mark it as accepted. Please provide the explanation also.

Comment: I put my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is ok but some little mistake found before slideDown() to call show() and append new li element content so do you need to display first element slide down after added top.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.dropdown').find('li:eq(0)').addClass('active');
    $('.dropdown').find('[data-id="parentmenu"]').each(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('active') == false) {
            $(this).find('ul').slideUp(10);
        }
    });
    $('ul.dropdown').on('click', '[data-id="parentmenu"]', function () {
        $(this).siblings('[data-id="parentmenu"]').removeClass('active');
        $(this).siblings('[data-id="parentmenu"]').each(function () {
            $(this).find('ul').slideUp(500);
        });
        $(this).addClass('active');
        //$(this).find('ul').show().slideDown(500);

        $markupHTML = "<li data-id='parentmenu'>" + $(this).html() + "</li>";
        $($markupHTML).insertBefore($('.dropdown').find('li:eq(0)'));
        $(this).remove();
        $('.dropdown').find('li:eq(0)').find('ul').slideDown(500);
    });

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w0d8sdvo/3/

Answer (score 0):

I'd suspect the $markupHTML rewriting is quite a likely candidate for your animation not to be working.. as it's creating/ rewriting DOM elements.

As a side note, I find the order of menu items moving around poor usability from a UX perspective.

Comment: How I am to move the menu items if not change the HTML. Any guidance on the same?